# How to resolve Skipping acquire of configured file Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

Tags: package-management, updates, update-manager, multiverse

How can I solve these issues?

```
Reading package lists... Done                      
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'multiverse/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'multiverse' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

My ubuntu is

```
ilyat@todorpc:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
```

My `/etc/apt/sources.list` is

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS _Bionic Beaver_ - Release amd64 (20180725)]/ bionic main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://ua.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic multiverse partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable
# deb-src [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu bionic stable
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic multiverse
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove `multiverse` from this line

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic multiverse partner
```

Comment: Why? How does this solve the problem? This answer might solve the problem for the original asker, but I am not sure how to adapt it more generally.

Comment: OP had a wrong line, so it fixed the problem. How can it be more general?

Answer (score 3):

Just replace the following file:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic multiverse partner
```

with

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
```

and `apt-get update`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, but the line was reading correctly as 
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner in
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list
So I commented it out, ran sudo apt-get update, then uncommented the line, and ran sudo apt-get update again, this seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I had bionic main and focal main checked, unchecked both line `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal main` and `apt-get update` and fitit successfully