# Typo in sources.list?

Tags: apt, software-sources

When I try to add a repository using apt, I got a message of a possible typo in sources.list, saying it didn't find a component 'restrited'. I manually edited all such lines to say 'restricted' (after backing up the original version of course) - which fixed it, just to run into a different typo.

```
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partner/source/Sources' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'partner' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partnet/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'partnet' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partnet/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'partnet' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partnet/i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'partnet' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partnet/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'partnet' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partnet/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'partnet' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partnet/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'partnet' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partnet/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'partnet' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partnet/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'partnet' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partnet/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' doesn't have the component 'partnet' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

I assumed that 'partner' is supposed to be 'partner', but first line proves that this isn't the case, since it can't find the component 'partner' either. Is it even worth it to fix this, or repositories will work normally without it?

**Is there any way I can check what this should be actually saying?**

Comment: I'd just open an editor (`sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list`) & fix it ... but note I'd not recommend vi/vim unless you're familiar with it.   `s/partnet/parter/` I assume is the fix but I'd check the whole file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve Skipping acquire of configured file Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121069/how-to-resolve-skipping-acquire-of-configured-file-ubuntu-18-04-2-lts) and/or [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/q/124017)

Comment: `partner` is only for the Canonical repo (`http://archive.canonical.com/`), not for the general Ubuntu repos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not every repository offers packages from every component. For example, the first repo in your list, http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/, offers packages from `main`, `multiverse`, `restricted` and `universe` (`by-hash` is something different). But you're asking this repo for a component `partner`, which it doesn't offer, so

> (...) repository (...) doesn't have the component 'partner' (component misspelt in sources.list?)

You'll want to go through your list of repositories. For each, you'll want to check which components the repo offers (from the directory structure, from the repo's description etc.) and which component contains the packages you're interested in. Then edit your `sources.list` accordingly.

Comment: Oh, so I can literally visit these addresses in a browser to check the contents? That helps, thank you!