# not proper acces to the system

Tags: package-management, updates, update-manager, repository

```
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main'./binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'.' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main'./binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'.' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main'./i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'.' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main'./i18n/Translation-en_IN' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'.' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main'./dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'.' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main'./dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'.' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main'./dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'.' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main'./dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'.' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main'./cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'.' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main'./binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-proposed InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'.' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main'./binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-proposed InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'.' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main'./i18n/Translation-en_IN' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-proposed InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'.' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main'./i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-proposed InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'.' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main'./dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-proposed InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'.' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main'./dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-proposed InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'.' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main'./dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-proposed InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'.' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main'./dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-proposed InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'.' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main'./cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-proposed InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main'.' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typo in sources.list?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1324377/typo-in-sources-list)