# W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe' case

Tags: package-management, update-manager

I want to upgrade my Ubuntu 21.10 to 22.04 version, but when I run `sudo apt-get update` I get the following output:

```
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease' doesn't 
have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

I found a similar [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121069/how-to-resolve-skipping-acquire-of-configured-file-ubuntu-18-04-2-lts) but with 'multiverse' problem and according to the solution I have to edtit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and replace `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic multiverse partner`with `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner`. In my file I have `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish partner universe`. In this way, I would like to know if that solution could be the same for my case.

[EDIT]

If I run `cat /etc/apt/resources.list`:

```
   1   | # deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 21.04 _Hirsute Hippo_ - Release amd64 (20210420)]/ hirsute main restricted
   2   │ 
   3   │ # See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
   4   │ # newer versions of the distribution.
   5   │ deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish main restricted
   6   │ # deb-src http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute main restricted
   7   │ 
   8   │ ## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
   9   │ ## distribution.
  10   │ deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates main restricted
  11   │ # deb-src http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates main restricted
  12   │ 
  13   │ ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
  14   │ ## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
  15   │ ## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
  16   │ deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish universe
  17   │ # deb-src http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute universe
  18   │ deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates universe
  19   │ # deb-src http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates universe
  20   │ 
  21   │ ## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
  22   │ ## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
  23   │ ## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
  24   │ ## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
  25   │ ## security team.
  26   │ deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish multiverse
  27   │ # deb-src http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute multiverse
  28   │ deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates multiverse
  29   │ # deb-src http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates multiverse
  30   │ 
  31   │ ## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
  32   │ ## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
  33   │ ## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
  34   │ ## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
  35   │ ## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
  36   │ deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-backports main restricted universe multiverse
  37   │ # deb-src http://mx.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-backports main restricted universe multiverse
  38   │ 
  39   │ ## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
  40   │ ## 'partner' repository.
  41   │ ## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
  42   │ ## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
  43   │ deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish partner universe
  44   │ # deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute partner
  45   │ 
  46   │ deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security main restricted
  47   │ # deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security main restricted
  48   │ deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security universe
  49   │ # deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security universe
  50   │ deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security multiverse
  51   │ # deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security multiverse
```

Also I have in that folder: `sources.list.d/`, `sources.list.distUpgrade` and `sources.list.save`.

Comment: The errors suggest that your sources are bad.  Edit your question with the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` Also include any other `.list` files under `/etc/apt` or any subdirectories

Comment: Do you have any idea why your sources include sources for both hirsute and impish? Mixing sources from different releases can wreak havoc on your package management which may be very difficult to recover from